# Compressing multiple equations into one JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, division

I have 5 equations in Javascript, all are very similar, they take a number value, divide it by 60, then multiply it by another value. e.g.:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 1;
var c = 1;
var d = 15.5;
var e = 5

var a1 = 10;
var b1 = 1;
var c1 = 10;
var d1 = 15;
var e1 = 5


var calcOne = (a/60)*a1
var calcTwo = (b/60)*b1
var calcThree = (c/60)*c1
var calcFour = (d/60)*d1
var calcFive = (e/60)*e1

var finalValue = (calcOne + calcTwo + calcThree + calcFour + calcFive)

**finalValue = 6.154**
```

The values of the first two sets of variables can change, they can be any number at all, even 0's, what I want to do is compress the 5 calculations into 1, so I want to be able to get the 'finalValue' (6.154) value from one equation, and I would want it to work regardless of what the values are, e.g. I don't want to have to hardcode it.

For example, I have tried

```
(((a+b+c+d+e)/60) * (a1+b1+c1+d1+e1)) = 22.2425  //sum of first set, divided by 60, multiplied by sum of second set (value too big)

(((a+b+c+d+e)/300) * (a1+b1+c1+d1+e1)) = 4.4485  //sum of first set, divided by 300, multiplied by sum of second set (divided by 300 as there are 5 equations)

((((a+b+c+d+e)/5)/60) * (a1+b1+c1+d1+e1)) = 4.4485  //sum of first set divided by 5 , divided by 60, multiplied by sum of second set (divided by 5 before 60 as there are 5 equations)

(((a+b+c+d+e)/60) * ((a1+b1+c1+d1+e1/5))) = 4.4485  //sum of first set, divided by 60, multiplied by sum of second set (divided by 5 as there are 5 equations)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: They're all multiplied by different factors, then added. You cannot change that order. However you can do this: https://jsfiddle.net/357rkezc/

Answer (score 1):

You could take all values into arrays and reduce the arrays.

```js
const
    a = [10, 1, 1, 15.5, 5],
    b = [10, 1, 10, 15, 5],
    r = a.reduce((s, v, i) => s + v * b[i], 0) / 60;

console.log(r); // 6.154
```

A slightly better approach is to use paired values.

```js
const
    values = [[10, 10], [1, 1], [1, 10], [15.5, 15], [5, 5]],
    r = values.reduce((s, [a, b], i) => s + a * b, 0) / 60;

console.log(r); // 6.154
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the formula as

```
(a * a1 + b * b1 + c * c1 + d * d1 + e * e1)/60;
```

```js
var a = 10;
var b = 1;
var c = 1;
var d = 15.5;
var e = 5

var a1 = 10;
var b1 = 1;
var c1 = 10;
var d1 = 15;
var e1 = 5


var calcOne = (a / 60) * a1
var calcTwo = (b / 60) * b1
var calcThree = (c / 60) * c1
var calcFour = (d / 60) * d1
var calcFive = (e / 60) * e1

var finalValue = (calcOne + calcTwo + calcThree + calcFour + calcFive);
var formula = (a * a1 + b * b1 + c * c1 + d * d1 + e * e1)/60;

console.log(finalValue,formula);
```

Comment: ?? that is literally hard-coding it, something OP didn't want to do

Comment: actually this looks like exactly what the OP wanted. And it's just algebra.

Comment: I think this is what the OP asked for

Comment: No, that is hard-coded. In case OP decides they need to add an f, a sixth term, what happens then? Would your suggestion be to just insert `+ f * f1`?

Comment: What do you mean OP wants to add an extra f? Its an algebraic equation, not an extended series

Comment: @NanoMiratus please note that all of the OPs attempts are inline with this answer... eg. `(((a+b+c+d+e)/60) * (a1+b1+c1+d1+e1)) = 22.2425 ` and they say *`so I want to be able to get the 'finalValue' (6.154) value from one equation'*

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achive the result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var a = 10;
var b = 1;
var c = 1;
var d = 15.5;
var e = 5;

var a1 = 10;
var b1 = 1;
var c1 = 10;
var d1 = 15;
var e1 = 5;


const first = [a, b, c, d, e];
const second = [a1, b1, c1, d1, e1];

const result = first.reduce((acc, curr, i) => acc + (curr / 60) * second[i], 0);
console.log(result);
```